# Tonalpohualli calculations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, calendar-computations, mathematical-astronomy

I was doing some math on the Tonalpohualli, the mexica ritual calendar. This calendar has 260 days divided in 13-days periods associated with 20 distinct symbols. Every 13-days period is called a *trecena*. The days in the calendar are marked as follows:

> 1 - Crocodile
> 2 - Wind
> 3 - House
> ...
> 11 - Monkey
> 12 - Grass
> 13 - Reed
> (We start a new trecena but continue with the rest of the 20 symbols)
> 1 - Jaguar
> 2 - Eagle
> 3 - Vulture
> ...
> 6 - Rain
> 7 - Flower (Now that we've run through the 20 symbols we start with crocodile again)
> 8 - Crocodile
> 9 - Wind
> 10 - House (We then run through the whole remaining days until we've completed 260 days)
> ...
> 12 - Rain
> 13 - Flower (This day is the 260th)

Due to the nature of 13 as a prime number, this cycle is repeated after 260 days (since $13 * 20 = 260$). The first day is, as we've seen, the 1-Crocodile and is written as $(1, 1)$; the 14th day is 1-Jaguar and is written as $(1 - 14)$ and for a last example the 21st day is 8-Crocodile and is written as $(8 - 1)$.

The general notation I will use here is $(N, S)$, standing for Number and Symbol. The 260th day is 13-xochitl (thirteen, flower) or $(13, 20)$. So, if I want to know which symbol and number will represent a day from 1 to 260 I do the following (in the example I will use $x=47$ as the day):

> $N = x-13c$, where x is the day number we chose and c is the quotient of dividing $x/13$
>
> $N = 47-13c$, where c is the quotient of dividing $47/13$, in this case 3
>
> $$N = 47-13(3) = 8$$ (The number associated with the 47th day is 8)
>
> And
>
> $S = x-20q$, where x is the day number and q is the quotient of dividing $x/20$
>
> $S = 47-20q$, where q is the quotient of $47/20$, in this case 2
>
> $$S = 47-20(2) = 7$$ (The symbol associated with the 47th is the seventh one, the Deer or Mazatl)
>
> Therefore, the 47th day is expressed in the Tonalpohualli as $(8, 7)$ or 8 - Deer.

My question is, if I am provided with the $(8, 7)$ pair, is it possible to recover back the original number I started with (in this case 47) by using some kind of inverse in the algorithms? For example, is it possible to determine which day number from 1 to 260 produces the $(3, 12)$ pair? Please refer to the image I've linked in the comments, I will clarify any doubt you have.

Comment: Presumably *Chinese remainder theorem* techniques will work

Comment: In the following image you can verify that the 47th day is indeed 8-mazatl (you count from top to bottom column by column)(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9-E37gu9pJx_Z2apQoIcZUh7iMBAczk_jci2RUYIMwxvZhPH3j4XZuinC

Comment: @Henry, could you expand on that? I'm not familiar to the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: The symboy $(N,S)$ is $N$ days after $S$ 13 day cycles so $x = N + 13S$.  So, you did the hard and complicated problem with no difficulty but the blindingly obvious one confuses you?

Comment: @fleablood, maybe you could take a look at the image I posted on the comments to see the motivation behind my calculations? I'm not sure I'm explaining perfectly the details.

Comment: Actually, looking at the image the second day is $(2,2)$ third is $(3,3)$ and so on and the forteenth is $(14, 1)$ and the twentieth is $(20,7)$ and the twenty first isn $(1, 8)$.  So it *is* harder but his alogirthim to begin with isn't correct.

Comment: It is correct, you can verify that the 47th day is (8, 7). You could aso use the algorithm to verify that the 260th day produces the (13, 20) pair, it is the 13-xochitl.

Comment: The 14th day actually is (1, 14) following the (number, symbol) notation due to the fact that numbers repeat in cycles of trecenas. The 20th day is (7, 20) The 21st is actually (8, 1) because it is the 8th day in the current count and falls on cipactli, the first symbol.

Comment: Ah,  I misunderstood your algorithm.  I thought you were doing $S = c+1$.  Okay, so the answer is the CRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image what we have is $(1,1)(2,2), (3,3).....(13,13),(14,1)....(19,12)(20,13)$.

Are you familiar with modulo notation?

You didn't describe the image well.

If $x = (N,S)$ then $x + 1 = (N+1, S+1)$ ...unless $N+1 =21$ in which case it bounces back to $1$ or if $S+1 =14$ in which case it bounces back to $1$>

This "circlular" arithmetic is called "modular arithetic" and it uses the following concept/notation:

$a \equiv b \mod n$ if $a\div n$ and $b\div n$ have the same remainder...

or in other words if $a = b + kn$ for some integer (maybe negative) $k$.....

or in other word if $a-b$ is divisible by $n$ ....

or in other words $a$ and $b$ both circle back to to the same number.

So::

If $x$ is the $x$th day of the year then $x = (N,S)$ and $N \equiv x \mod 20$ and $1 \le N \le 20$ and $S\equiv x \mod 13$ and $1 \le S \le 20$.

And that is your algorithm.

There is a theorem, called the Chinese remainder Theorem, that says:

If $\gcd(n,m) =1$ ($n$ and $m$ have no prime factors in common) then

$x \equiv a \mod n$

and $x \equiv b\mod m$.  Then $x \equiv c \mod n*m$ will have one unique solution where $1 \le c \le n*m$.

You can solve it by noting that $x = a + kn = b+jm$ will have a single answer between $1$ and $n*m$.

And so for day $x$ you will have $(N,S)$ where $N \equiv x \mod 20$ and $S\equiv x \mod 13$.

So the answer to $x = (N,S)$ will be $x = N\mod 20$ and $x =S\mod 20$ is the Chinese remainder theorem.

Ex.

$(N=7, S=8)\implies x \equiv 7 \mod 20 \implies x = 7 + 20n$

And $x \equiv 8 \mod 13 \implies x = 8 + 13s$.

So $7 + 20n = 8 + 13s$ so $1 = 20n - 13s$.

$20*2 =40$ and $3*19 = 39$ and so $1 = 20(2) - 13(3)$

So $n =2; s=3$ so $x = 7+ 2*20 = 8 + 3*13 = 47$.

Comment: Not really, I am asking that provided a pair of numbers representing a date in the Tonalpohualli, I can recover which day number from1 to 260 produces that pair.

Comment: Uh...... So if you are given $(N,S)$ where $N$ is the day number and $S$ is the symbol number the day of the year is $x= N + 13S$.  That is the day number from 1 to 260 that will produce that pair.

Comment: @MorganRodgers.  Oops.

Comment: But there is no year involved in the calculations. If we follow your result, then for N=8 and S=7, x = 99, which of course we know it's not true because the pair (8, 7) is produced by the number 47, not 99.

Comment: Year?!?!?!?  What the heck does the *year* have to do with it?  You never said *anything* about a year in either the image *or* the question.  And you description of the question does not match what the image does at all.

Comment: That's what I wanted to say, the year has nothing to do with it. The image just shows the whole Tonalpohualli cycles arranged in rows and columns. My algorithm determines when will a certain day between 1 and 260 will fall on the Tonalpohualli.

Comment: If the year had nothing to do with it why did you bring it up??????

Comment: Your algorithm and your description has nothing to do with what the image shows.  You description and algorithe describe $(1,1)(2,1)....(20,1),(1,2)(2,2)....$.  In that case we have $x = N + (S-1)*13$ and $N \equiv x \mod 20$ and $S = \lfloor \frac xS\rfloor + 1$.  !!!!BUT!!! That is not what your image is.

Comment: Because you said "the day of the year" and I just misinterpreted what you said, apologies.

Comment: The image is $(1,1)(2,2),(3,3)......(x\mod 20, x \mod 13)$.  ANd that is a different issue and my current answer.

Comment: Maybe so you can check the validity of my algorithm try it out with the 21st day and you will get (8, 1) with no doubt. The algorithm is correct, but what I'm asking is the converse, given (8, 1) am I able of obtaining the original "21" number?

Comment: Ah, now with your last update I think I understand what needs to be done, so your results are correct but so is my algorithm. My algorithm simply gives the pair associated to a day. Could you explain me what the Chinese Remainder Theorem is all about? I have read Wikipedia but I don't fully understand it.

Comment: I appologize.  Your alogrithm is correct.  Read up on the chinese remainder problem and modulo arithemetic.

Comment: Sure, thanks! I'll mark your answer as the accepted one in a couple of minutes just to make sure no one wants to comment anything else. Thanks again!